# How to create a valid XML tree root element in using only PHP?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

How to create a valid XML tree using only PHP?

I have been running into many troubles with creating an XML tree just using PHP. I already have some code to show where I am at right now:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$verb = $xml->createElement ('verb');
$vtext = $xml->createTextNode($_POST['verb']);
$verb->appendChild($vtext);
$xml->appendChild ($verb);


$adverb = $xml->createElement ('adverb');
$advtext = $xml->createTextNode($_POST['adverb']);
$adverb->appendChild($advtext);
$xml->appendChild ($adverb);
$xml ->save("'".$_POST[verb]."'.xml") or die ("error creating file");
```

So, with this and the user input, it creates a file that is whatever the verb is. The only thing is, I keep getting error messages that there is extra content below the verbs.

I know that this is because I'm not adding a *root element*, but how exactly would you add this root element without creating errors? There are very little forums even talking about PHP and XML alone, so it's hard to find one that's about making an XML tree.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem. One thing that I noticed that was strange is the ' in the save shouldn't be there unless you want a file name `'run'.xml`

Comment: and you should probably should do some checks on verb prior to saving a file there...

Comment: @Orangepill Do you know how to change this? I have that same problem, but a truly minor one. By the way, it's because there is no root element with two parent elements

Comment: php 5.4.6 let it fly without complaining. got two elements with no document element. Based on this very dated O'Reilly book that I am looking at though a Document Element (root node) is required to be valid xml.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$root = $xml->createElement ('root');
$xml->appendChild($root);

$verb = $xml->createElement ('verb');
$vtext = $xml->createTextNode($_POST['verb']);
$verb->appendChild($vtext);
$root->appendChild ($verb);


$adverb = $xml->createElement ('adverb');
$advtext = $xml->createTextNode($_POST['adverb']);
$adverb->appendChild($advtext);
$root->appendChild ($adverb);
$xml ->save("'".$_POST[verb]."'.xml") or die ("error creating file");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample i have found in stackoverflow and this work for me! hope this will also help you!

```
<?php    
    /* create a dom document with encoding utf8 */
    $domtree = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

    /* create the root element of the xml tree */
    $xmlRoot = $domtree->createElement("xml");
    /* append it to the document created */
    $xmlRoot = $domtree->appendChild($xmlRoot);

    $currentTrack = $domtree->createElement("track");
    $currentTrack = $xmlRoot->appendChild($currentTrack);

    /* you should enclose the following two lines in a cicle */
    $currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('path','song1.mp3'));
    $currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('title','title of song1.mp3'));

    $currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('path','song2.mp3'));
    $currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('title','title of song2.mp3'));

    /* get the xml printed */
    echo $domtree->saveXML();
?>
```

Comment: This creates just a string for me.

Answer (score 0):

> How exactly would you add this root element without creating errors?

For a `DOMDocument` (in general, not only for the PHP extension), the *`documentElement`* (often also called *root element*) is technically a child-node of the *`DOMDocument`* object.

You create it by appending it (as you already do (!)):

```
$xml  = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$root = $xml->createElement ('root');
$xml->appendChild($root);
```

The new *`documentElement`* now is available as:

```
$xml->documentElement;
```

Try it your own ([online Demo](http://eval.in/32559)):

```
$xml  = new DOMDocument("1.0");

$xml->save('php://output'); // document is empty
```

The output is just the XML declaration, no root element:

Then adding the root element (here named *root*):

```
$root = $xml->createElement ('root');
$xml->appendChild($root); 
$xml->save('php://output'); // document has root-node now
```

And the Document has a Root-Node now as the output shows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root/>
```

The `$root` is the *`documentElement`* now and Children can be appended to it:

```
$root->appendChild($xml->createTextNode("\n  "));
$root->appendChild($xml->createElement('hello', 'world'));
$root->appendChild($xml->createTextNode("\n  "));
$root->appendChild($xml->createElement('answer', '42'));
$root->appendChild($xml->createTextNode("\n  "));
$root->appendChild($xml->createElement('danger', 'danger'));
$root->appendChild($xml->createTextNode("\n"));

$xml->save('php://output');
```

The output then is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <hello>world</hello>
  <answer>42</answer>
  <danger>danger</danger>
</root>
```